# Configure launch.json for typescript debug in VS Code

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, source-maps

This is my launch.json configuration file for VS Code.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [{
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/server/server.ts",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/build/server",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "smartStep": true,
        "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy"]
    }, {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Attach to Process",
        "port": 5858,
        "outFiles": [],
        "sourceMaps": true
    }]
}
```

I can't figure out why I can put breakpoints only on server.ts file even if the code is compiled with sourcemaps.

I compile the code with gulp-typescript as below

```
var tsProject = p.typescript.createProject(cfg.tsconfig);

return gulp.src(cfg.src)
    .pipe(p.plumber({
        errorHandler: p.notify.onError('Typescript SERVER error: <%= error.message %>')
    }))
    .pipe(p.sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
    .pipe(tsProject())
    .pipe(p.sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(cfg.dest))
    .pipe(p.notify({
        title: 'Typescript SERVER',
        message: 'Server compiled!',
        onLast: true
    }));
```

And this is my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "outDir": "./../../build",
        "rootDir": "./../"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "./../client"
    ]
}
```